# Allow Layout View and Other Views to use the same Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using ASP.NET MVC with Razor syntax. I'm trying to find the best way to obtain data and pass that around my application for access by both the layout view (shared) and other views. In some cases, additional model(s) may need to be passed to views. I've looked at items like the **BaseViewModel**, but for that, I'd need to pass a model on every ActionResult that would use it. The data changes for every user and could change during the same session.

What's the best way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a BaseViewModel and make MyModel a child of this model (ie: `public class MyModel:BaseViewModel`). In this BaseViewModel put all the common properties that your layout has to use.

After, you need to put in your shared layout:

```
@model BaseViewModel
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question as a bit vague but I *think* that you are asking how to get a model to the layout?

I would ***not*** create a `BaseViewModel` for that since it isn't really a `is-a` relationship.

Instead I would do something like I describe here: http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/getting-information-into-the-layout-without-using-viewbag/